# How to enable Three Finger Drag from command line

Tags: terminal, macos, trackpad, system-settings

I'm trying to write a shell script that will automatically set the trackpad to use the three-finger-drag option that you can find in the system preferences. I've tried a number of different things, but none of them seem to work. Here's what I've got right now:

```
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad TrackpadThreeFingerDrag -bool true
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadThreeFingerDrag -bool true
```

I've scoured all the settings I could find from the output of `defaults read`, but I've found nothing else useful. These are the settings that system-prefs changes when I manually change the settings. Is this a bug?

I'm running Mavericks on a 13-inch mid 2012 MacBook Air. The three-finger-drag works fine when I enable it manually.

EDIT: I restart my machine each time I run this.

Comment: This worked for me on macOS Catalina. It required a log out+in to take effect. The weird thing is that the UI in the accessibility preferences was not updated to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 7):

It took a lot of trial and error, but I figured it out:

```
 defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerSwipeGesture -int 1
```

You don't need to restart your machine after you enter this command for the setting to apply. Logging out of your account and logging back in again is sufficient.

Comment: It doesn't work on Yosemite!

Comment: On El Capitan, the original code (from the question) is working now.. 
Maybe Apple switched drivers

Comment: What about Sierra

Answer (score 0):

This worked on macOS Monterey along with a logout/login cycle:

```sh
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad DragLock -bool false
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Dragging -bool false
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad TrackpadThreeFingerDrag -bool true
```